# ASP.NET pages crash IIS7 app pool

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-7.5, application-pools

I'm running IIS7.5 on Server 2008 R2.  I've got an app pool under which I have running a WCF web service, an .asmx web service and an ASP.NET site.  Anytime I try to hit any of the ASP.NET pages, the app pool crashes.  The entries in the application log in Event Viewer all look like this:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
```

I've tried getting Windows Error Reporting to give me a crash dump when this happens as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), but to no avail.  I have this same set of applications running on an app pool on my development machine, which is IIS7.5 on Win7, and it works fine.  As near as I can tell all of the settings for the app pool and the web apps are the same for both.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/an-iis-crash-analysis-story/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I haven't been able to solve this problem yet, but that blog entry has given me a good jumping off point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally getting the correct rule set up on DebugDiag so that I could get a dump for this, I was able to pinpoint the problem - there was a versioning error between the ASP.NET pages I had deployed and a COM+ module that they use, and it was causing an unhandled exception that then caused an infinite loop of unhandled exceptions when it tried to log the error, thus crashing my app pool.